# Adding a caption to IMG SRC when you need the text to stay on the right

Tags: image, caption

how would I add a small caption under this image while keeping the text to the right?

```
<img src=".jpg" alt="lorum ipsum" width="350" height="240" class="alignleft size-medium wp-image-159" >
```

Many thanks.

Comment: Float a text label right as well as CSS `clear: both;` ?